# Не отрабатывает оператор && в условии

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Не отрабатывает часть условие. Чтоб было понятно опишу словесно принцип. В инпут выводиться тест в случае если : enable == true (инпут не до конца заполнен), или valid == false (нету совпадений по символам). Нужно чтоб тест выводился при любом из этих условий(и если импут нед до конца заполнен и если нет совпадений).

Вот часть кода которая, отвичает за это условие : `} else if (enable == true && valid == false  ) {`

Следующая ошибка в похожем условии :  `enable == false && valid == true` здесь при одновременном соблюдении enable == false и valid == true должно выскакивать сообщение alert. Но событие срабатывает когда 11 цыфр в поле , а должно срабатывать когда 12.

вот весь код условия :

```
   var phone = this.value;
                if (!phone || phone.replace(/\D/g, '').length < 12) enable = false;
                if (codes[phone.substr(5, 3)]) {
                    valid = true
                } else if (enable == true && valid == false  ) {
                    $('.form-control').val('Некорректный ввод');
                }
                if (enable == false && valid == true) {
                    obj = {
                        dates: 'дата',
                        time: 'время',
                        phone: phone
                    };
                    obj['date'] = retite
                    alert(obj['date']);
                }
            }).end().end()
```

вот весь код примера : http://jsfiddle.net/0xL0fctq/35/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (enable == true && valid == false) alert(1);
```

– алерт отработает только если одновременно первое значение будет истинным, а второе ложным. Если вы хотите, чтобы срабатывало при выполнении одного из условий, используйте оператор `||` вместо `&&`.

> Но событие срабатывает когда 11 цыфр в поле , а должно срабатывать
>   когда 12.

```
if (!phone || phone.replace(/\D/g, '').length < 12) enable = false;
```

– замените или строгий знак неравенства `<` на `<=`, или число 12 на 13.

Comment: @ Дмитрий , а не подскажите почему если убрать одну цифру с инпута, то сработает событие алерт вместо , того чтоб вывелась ошибка в инпут?  P.S Я исправил всё как Вы указали.

Comment: @Valeriy1996, а что алертит? Я надеюсь, вы первую строку моего ответа не скопировали себе в код? Я её для наглядности привёл. Вам там только оператор поменять нужно.

Comment: @ Дмитрий ,нет я так сделал как вы и сказали. Алерт у меня в коде есть он срабатывает когда в инпуте 12 знаков , я исправил в условии на 13. Но когда с инпута один убираешь то вместо того, чтоб сработало условие которое выводит ошибку в инпут срабатывает алерт который "говорит, что все верно"

Comment: @ Дмитрий, получаеться когда, добавляешь символы в поле то , работает как надо , а когда удаляешь , то всё наоборот, он почему то, думает, что всё символы на месте , вот , что странно...

Comment: @Valeriy1996 В примере по ссылке из вашего вопроса алерт не отрабатывает ни с моими правками, ни без них. А вот сообщение о некорректном вводе появляется с завидной регулярностью. Тут я вам увы помочь не смогу. Я не слишком дружу с JS, а мой ответ, равно как и ваш первоначальный вопрос, был чисто логического характера (с этим у меня проблем нет).

Comment: @ Дмитрий но всё же спасибо за ответ